# How can I block hidden button on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hidden

I am working on a html which already works integrated on a application. On this html there was 3 buttons and I add new one. This 3 button showen together when you click anyone on screen but new one do not seem. How can its possible. How can I solve this problem.

This is what I want:

[image]

(When I click Navigation button all buttons seen, but when I click another button new button do not seem which named 180 day Documents)

This situation valid for all button without "Navigation" but I could not load picture. I mean when You click to second button too, New button do not seem.

When you click Third button:

[image]

(Same problem valid too when click view button)

For this html there was a ready html and I add new button on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pwietp.css" media="screen" id="screenCSS" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" id="printCSS" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/evoslider/evoslider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.combined.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ietp-common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ietp-nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ietp-search.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="bar">
<div id="menu"><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
<div id="logoDiv"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" /></div>
<form id="search_toolbar" method="get" action="/solr/select">
<input id="searchinput" type="text" name="q" value="search" size="28" maxlength="140" onfocus="searchBarOnFocus(this)" onblur="searchBarOnBlur(this)" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="tabcontainer">
<div id="tabs" class="nav">
<span><a id="navtab" href="#" class="btn-highlight">Navigation</a></span>
<span><a id="searchtab" href="/solr/select" class="btn">Search</a></span>
<span><a id="viewtab" href="#" class="btn">View</a></span>
<span><a id="180DayDocumentstab" href="#" class="btn">180 Day Documents</a></span>
<div class="outer-container"><div class="container">
<div id="navigationContainer"><div class="navSection">
<div class="outer-container"><div class="container">
<div class="header navigationPMTitle"><span class="crumb" id="crumb">
<a href="#" id="homeLink">Home</a> 
<span>|</span>Issue No: 013<span>|</span>Issue Date:

                                    2017-02-01</div></div><div id="navSortButtons" class="header navSortButtons">Sort by:
                                    <a href="#" class="sort_button" id="sortCommonTitle">Tile</a> 
                                    <a href="#" class="sort_button" id="sortTechname">Techname</a> 
                                    <a href="#" class="sort_button" id="sortInfoname">Infoname</a> 
                                    <a href="#" class="sort_button" id="sortDMC">DMC</a></div></div>
                                    <div class="navSection"><div id="navigationFolders">
                                    <div class="navTitleDiv"><h3 class="removeBottomPadding">Contents</h3></div>
                                    <div id="navigationFoldersDiv">

<ul class="treeView" name="treeView">

</ul>
</div></div>
<div id="navigationDocuments">
<div id="navDocumentsTitleSection" class="navTitleDiv hide"><h3 class="removeBottomPadding" id="navDocumentsTitle"></h3></div>
<div id="navigationDocumentsDiv"></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<div id="footer">
<a href="javascript:openLegal()" id="proprietaryLink">International Aero Engines Proprietary Information © 2014 - 2017.</a>
<a href="javascript:openLegal()" id="exportLink">EAR Export Classification: Not subject to the EAR per 15 C.F.R. Chapter 1, Part 734.3(b)(3).</a></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you upload CSS as well?

Comment: can u elobrate your problem . be specfic

Comment: Maybe it's a copy mistake, but you have 2 closing spans at the end of your 4th span. And a span at the end of all your code that doesn't close.

Comment: Add also javascript code.

Comment: Actually second span do not valid for a turn. I tried that. Could not solved. Thank you @Gobbin.

Comment: elobrate? @rupesh

Comment: Why are you closing 180 Day Documents</a></span></span>  twice?

Comment: I would recommend you try your best to recreate the problem at https://jsfiddle.net/ this will give people something to work with and debug.

Comment: Edited with all code @maximelian1986

Comment: I just tried after edit. Now we have a just </span>. problem is still valid @DincaAdrian

Comment: I tried @NewToJS on javascript not onjs.fiddle. I could not solve this problem and because of that I create a tag here. If we can solve this problem I will edit my tag to people can see and if there are a any problem which somebody is living can solve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if i copy your code (only the `span` tags) and i remove the closing span after the `<a id="180dayDocumentsTab">` all the `span` tags show up on my screen. Remove the `</span>` after this anchor tag and you'll be good to go.

```
<span><a id="180DayDocumentstab" href="#" class="btn">180 Day Documents</a></span>
```

Comment: Well i copied all your code even after you edited it and it shows up on my screen. So i don't know what is the problem now. :)

Comment: Also, now that we are at it (:D). What does this do? <span class="crumb" id="crumb">. You aren't closing this tag either.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `<span class="crumb" id="crumb">` because it's ruining your divs after that. Use fiddle Tidy option to help you get a nicer code and it will help you get a look on missing closing tags or any other small code errors. A clear code will make you spot any mistake much faster.